# Is it easy to guess random seed from generated numbers?

Tags: python, c, random, cryptography

I need to implement deterministic randomization of some private data. I.e. we have some original UUID, then we use its `md5` hash to seed a RNG and generate a new UUID like this:

```
input hashlib, uuid, random

# seed RNG
hex_seed = hashlib.md5(original_uuid.encode()).hexdigext()
seed = int(hex_seed, 16)
random.seed(seed)
# generate new UUID
val = random.getrandbits(128)
new_uuid = str(uuid.UUID(int=val))
```

Original values may be not only UUIDs but also usernames or other data, as well as resulting values, hence `md5` hashing. But the most important is UUID.

Now the question is: how hard is it for an attacker to calculate original UUID value given resulting UUID?

MD5 could be reversed using rainbow tables. But is it hard to reverse Python's build-in RNG to determine its seed value from 128 generated bytes? I tried to find it out myself but got stuck a bit.
So far I could find out that `getrandbits(128)` results in 4 calls to `genrand_int32`, and that out `seed()` call results in `init_by_array` being called with an array of 4 32-bit integers.

References:
1. Python's RNG source code (in C): https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#l231

Comment: I am not an expert in security, but I believe the private data is safe, if uncovering it depends of guessing the seed of the generated random number. I say that because, even if it is possible to guess the seed, the attacker should know he needs to do this step... You could also make it more complex for the attacker, using the first random number of the sequence generated of the given seed to be the position of the random-generated sequence you are using on your hash, like this `n = rand(seed) for i in range(0, n) key = nextRand()`

Comment: *"Now the question is: how hard is it for an attacker to calculate original UUID value given resulting UUID?"* - this is really a question for a different site. See [Second pre-image resistance vs Collision resistance](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20997/10496) on [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Don't do it like that! You are assuming stuff about the seeding-process which is a very bad idea. Just use the original *salted* (rainbow-tables!) crypto-hash (maybe not MD5, but SHA2/3 or something similar) as bit-source and trim out your number / as many bits you need.

Comment: I don't get the upvotes for that comment above. It's ignoring the weak link in this chain (seeding) and from a cryptographic-perspective i also think he is asking about *Pre-image resistance*.

Comment: I don't see any guarantees that random generator is cryptographically secure.  It seems likely this setup can be broken.